# Is a service account the right credentials for querying google bigquery in node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-bigquery, jwt

I have created a service account in the Google API Console, downloaded the .p12 file, and now I am trying to use https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple to sign the request for a token.

Where/How should I get the 'secret' for signing it with HS256?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem with the openssl command I was using. In case anybody runs into the same issue make sure to use "-nodes" parameter like so:

openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out file.pem -nodes

Then just pass the content of the .pem file as the key for signing the token.

Good luck!